# Adding mocked class to stl container

Tags: c++, stl, googletest, googlemock

I'm writing a unit test on a class that contains a vector of objects.  I've been trying to mock the objects in the vector, but I keep running into problems overriding the base class.
Sample code:

book.hpp

```
class Book {
    std::string _author;
    std::string _title;

    virtual std::string getBookLabel() {
        ostringstream ostream;
        ostream << _title << " " << _author << std::endl;
        return ostream.str();
    } 
};
```

library.hpp

```
class Library {
    std::vector< Book > _books;

    std::string getBookLabels() {
       ostringstream ostream;
       for( auto i : _books ) {
           ostream << i.getBookLabel();
       }
       return ostream.str()
    }

    void addBook( Book &book ) {
       _books.push_back(book);
    }
};
```

test_library.cpp

```
TEST_F(TEST,test_get_book_labels) {
   class MockBook : public Book{
        MOCK_METHOD0(getLabel,std::string());
   };

   Library library;
   MockBook mockBook;
   EXPECT_CALL(mockBook,getLabel).
         WillOnce(Return(std::string("MockLabel")));
   Library.addBook(mockBook);

   std::string expected = "MockLabel";
   std::string actual = library.getBookLabels();
   ASSERT_EQ(expected, actual);
   // fails, actual contains "" because getBookLabels()
   // called Book::getBookLabel() instead of 
   // Mock::getBookLabel()
```

Is there a way to make Library::GetBookLabels() call MockBook::GetBookLabel()   ?

Late edit:  I'm surprised this isn't a more common problem, which is why I hoped I was missing some gmock feature.

Comment: Shouldn't `std::vector<< Book >>` be `std::vector<Book>`? (one set of <>)

Answer (score 1):

No. A `std::vector<Book>` can only hold instances of `Book`. It can never hold instances of `MockBook`.

You could work around this by having a vector of pointers (which can point to either Book or MockBook objects). If you want to go this route I would recommend using something like a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Book>>`, not a `std::vector<Book*>`, in order to avoid accidental memory leaks and such. (Learn about `unique_ptr` if you haven't already)

However, do you really need mocking in this case? Why not just create a normal `Book` that has the label you want?

Comment: I tried replacing std::vector<> with std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Book>> .  That created a whole new set of problems where I just couldn't get  EXPECT_CALL (*mockBook) do what I wanted to do.   Plus  I'm overcomplicating Library for the sake of unit testing - a bad pattern IMO.   Why not use Book - my real 'Book' class has a lot more side effects than my example, which is why I want to mock it.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend changing an applications data structures significantly to make mock-based testing easier. Now, in this case, it all seems a bit hastily designed (or maybe it's just a simplified example), but still. Other than that I agree with everything you said so +1.

Comment: It is a hasty, simplified example.  My 'real' Book::getBookLabel() call is much more complicated - which is why I want to mock it.  It is also better encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

What about making your `Library` a template like

```
template <class TBook>
class GenericLibrary { ... } ;
```

Then do a `typedef` or (more modern) `using`

```
using Library = GenericLibrary<Book>;
```

in your application code and it will just compile like before.

In your unit tests you do a

```
using MockLibrary = GenericLibrary<MockBook>;
```

Comment: It's an interesting idea but it doesn't seem to scale well.  If I modernize my library and add vector<coffee>; vector<Donuts>; then I've now got a three type template class.

Comment: On the other hand: if you *really* wanted to modernize it, you would replace the books in your library with eBooks and you would be done with one single typedef :D